# What does modular space $\mathbb{H}/ \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ mean?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, quotient-spaces

Juts a quick question. In Freitag's *Complex Analysis* as an example for The Quotient Topology it comes:

> The "modular space" $\mathbb{H}/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}).$

Every element in $\mathbb{H}$ can be mapped by a linear fractional transformation in $\mathbb{H}/ \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ to some fixed element ${\{\tau_0}\}$ in $\mathbb{H}$ so is it true to say $\mathbb{H}/ \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \cong {\{\tau_0}\}$? So basically a modular space is just any single point in $\mathbb{H}$?

I have a little background in Modular Forms so much appreciated a simple explanation.

Comment: $\Gamma = \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a group of biholomorphisms $\mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{H}$. Let $ \Gamma \tau = \{ \gamma \tau, \gamma \in \Gamma\}$ a subset of $\mathbb{H}$. Then $\Gamma \setminus \mathbb{H} = \{ \Gamma \tau, \tau \in  \mathbb{H}\}$ is a topological space whose points are subsets of  $\mathbb{H}$. The topology is the complex topology inherited from $\mathbb{H}$ so it is a Riemann surface. For any $\Gamma \tau$ there is a representative with $\gamma\tau \in \mathcal{F}$ the fundamental domain mentioned by carmichael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While all elements of $\mathbb{H}$ are $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$-equivalent, this is no longer the case if $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{Z}$. If (as you say) you have some background in modular forms, you've likely seen a picture of the standard fundamental domain for the modular group:
$$ \mathcal{F}=\{z=x+iy:y>0,-\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2},|z|\geq 1\}$$
You can visualize the quotient space by gluing together the boundary of $\mathcal{F}$: the points $-\frac{1}{2}+y$ and $\frac{1}{2}+y$ are identified, as are $z$ and $-\frac{1}{z}$ if $z\in\mathcal{F},|z|=1$.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake about $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and I know the $\mathcal{F}$. But for clarification: so is it true that $\mathbb{H}/ \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong$ any *single* point in $\mathbb{H}$; and $\mathbb{H}/ \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Yes, the quotient $\mathbb{H}/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ can be identified with a single point

Comment: And $\mathbb{H}/ \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathcal{F}?$

Comment: Not sure what $\cong$ means in this context. And don't forget that the boundary of $\mathcal{F}$ must be handled correctly.

Comment: ≅ means that the two spaces are homemorphic.

Comment: Well, then sure, if you identify the boundary points correctly and give $\mathcal{F}$ the quotient topology